# What's the difference between pd.DatetimeIndex.weekday and pd.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek

Tags: python, pandas

In pandas datetimeindex, [dayofweek](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofweek.html) and [weekday](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.weekday.html) seem to be the same.  Are they just aliases of each other?  I discovered these functions [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#time-date-components)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the `pandas` source code definition of `DatetimeIndex`, `weekday` is just an alias for `dayofweek`, so there is no difference.

```
class DatetimeIndex:
    ...
    dayofweek = _field_accessor('dayofweek', 'dow',
                                "The day of the week with Monday=0, Sunday=6")
    weekday = dayofweek
```

Source: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/50930a9879b580ab4f30d8b741229391e41afa76/pandas/tseries/index.py#L1547